# How to open readme URL for NuGet package?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

In NuGet, you can put a readme.txt in the root of the pacakge and it will open automatically. However, I have seen NuGet packages open a URL upon installation. How is this done (you can see an example with [this NuGet package](http://goo.gl/0y31F)).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is done through a PowerShell script in the package's tools\install.ps1 file. [Download the Glimpse package](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Glimpse/1.0.1) package, extract the archive, look for the tools\install.ps1 file.

At the bottom, you'll find the following script which performs the navigation:

```
$DTE.ItemOperations.Navigate("http://getglimpse.com/Version/Install/?" + $package.Id + "=" + $package.Version)
```

Comment: Or just use `start <url>`

Comment: Remember to include your scripts in your nuspec files
`<file src="tools\*.*" target="tools" />`

Comment: Note that `Install.ps` no longer works in NuGet 3, and there are no plans for bringing it back: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1020.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a powershell script to your package:

- `Init.ps1` runs when you first install a package into a solution
- `Install.ps1` runs every time a 
  package is installed into a project.

Source: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Automatically_Displaying_a_Readme.txt_File_During_Package_Installation