# How to distribute a .NET library

Tags: c#, .net, sdk

My organization is releasing an SDK to help .NET developers more easily interact with our API. We would like to support the right distribution options to meet developer needs.

What options exist for distributing the .NET library today? What are the pros and cons of each distribution channel?

Comment: There is no "recommended" way. If its a free library, I think NuGet is perfectly fine for a distribution channel. You should also offer to download pre-built DLLs via your website but I would direct people to the NuGet package first, since it can be updated easily.

Comment: @RonBeyer - thanks! Sounds like good advice.

Comment: My question has been edited to be less opinion based. Should it still be On Hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NuGet is, by far, the most convenient option for a library. Unlike standalone DLLs, it can be updated easily (and with notifications for updates), its dependencies are automatically pulled in (which avoids the "I have 40 DLLs in my libs/ folder, which ones do I actually need?" problem), and it's easier for VCS (no binaries taking up space).

You can also publish a symbols package, as explained [here](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-symbol-package), to help developers debug code that uses your library.
Some package authors ([Microsoft included](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples)) even publish "samples" packages that show how to use their packages.
Another option for easy documentation is to have your package automatically open its documentation website when downloaded, [using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401521/how-to-open-readme-url-for-nuget-package).

For the love of all that is holy, please do not force developers to install your SDK with an actual installer that copies files on the system unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: It sounds like if we were to provide DLLs, we would want to discourage that route and encourage the usage of NuGet. Right? I like the idea of publishing a "samples" package to show usage of the packages.

Comment: @JimmyZ: Yes, if you want to provide DLLs, it should be viewed as a fallback for people who cannot use NuGet. That'll also help you; it's easier to explain how to check for updates, and you'll get less devs complaining about bugs from old versions.

Answer (score 1):

One good way is source code version control. Keep the source on your server and authorize your clients to retrieve and compile the library in their projects.

AFAICT the most popular approach is downloading compiled DLL's / NuGet, though having the source makes much more sense for development and debugging.

Comment: I would keep the source on a separate server, like GitHub. That way the source is easily obtained through an open client.

Comment: "Your server" is not necessarily your own in-house server